# Authenticate Nifi using OpenID Connect using API

Tags: apache-nifi, openid-connect

I am new to OpenID connect & security domain. I have configured Nifi to use OpenID for authentication using online documentation. And to automate a few nifi related tasks we are using nipyapi.

I have already written python code which does automated flow deployment for basic nifi installation (unsecured & without user authentication)

Now, I have to move the code to secured Nifi installation. How to authenticate to OpenID connect using nipyapi/rest API ?

AS per discussion with Bryan, i am planning to use client certificate for authentication but it started giving authorization error. and have created another question with the details.
[Nifi - Client Certificate Authorization Error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447542/nifi-client-certificate-authorization-error)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OpenID Connect generally requires that you follow a flow of re-directs, typically in the browser. NiFi re-directs you to the login page of the OIDC provider, upon completion, the OIDC provider redirects you back to NiFi. I'm not exactly sure how, or if you even can, perform this login process from scripts. An easy alternative would be to just generate a client certificate to represent an automation user for any NiPyApi scripts. Client certificate authentication is always enabled by default for NiFi.

Comment: I agree, But does Nifi allows 2 authentications mechanism at the same time(not for the same user though).  We already have users who will be authenticated by OpenID Connect.

Comment: NiFi allows client certs, spnego, and one identity provider, all at the same time

Comment: Basically client certs and spnego are always enabled when secured and are checked first

Comment: great. Thanks Bryan. I will try this now. Any documentation/steps which will help me do this.

Comment: Depends how you generated the server certs for NiFi, you basically need a JKS or P12 file for a client cert that is signed by the same CA that generated your NiFi server certs

Comment: For my testing, i am using nifi toolkit for certificate generation and it is generating p12 & password file fo client as well

Comment: It seems i am almost there but stuck at the last point. In the logs, it says I am able to autheniticate but access denied errors..

```2019-08-10 11:26:42,594 INFO [NiFi Web Server-23] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Authentication success for CN=nifi-admin, OU=NIFI
2019-08-10 11:26:42,598 INFO [NiFi Web Server-23] o.a.n.w.a.c.AccessDeniedExceptionMapper identity[CN=nifi-admin, OU=NIFI], groups[] does not have permission to access the requested resource. No applicable policies could be found. Returning Forbidden response.```

Comment: I have created another question regarding nifi certificate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57447542/nifi-client-certificate-authorization-error

Comment: Hi Sunil, is there a way to get some help from you? we are stuck in the same situation and don't see a light at the end of the tunnel. much appreciated if some sample script