# Nifi - Client Certificate Authorization Error

Tags: apache-nifi, nipyapi

I have installed secured Nifi installation and wanted to authenticate using secured client certificate. Authentication went fine but it failed at authorization

`AccessDeniedExceptionMapper identity[CN=nifi-admin, OU=NIFI], groups[] does not have permission to access the requested resource. No applicable policies could be found. Returning Forbidden response.`

Please note that it is fresh installation and the idea is to use the nipyapi for automating admin tasks. (without logging into UI)

I have created certifcates using following command

`bin/tls-toolkit.sh standalone -n {FQDN}  -C "CN=nifi-admin,OU=NIFI"`

Also, I have added same CN in authorizers.xml file like this.

```
        <identifier>file-access-policy-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileAccessPolicyProvider</class>
        <property name="User Group Provider">file-user-group-provider</property>
        <property name="Authorizations File">./conf/authorizations.xml</property>
        <property name="Initial Admin Identity">CN=nifi-admin,OU=NIFI</property>
        <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>
        <property name="Node Identity 1"></property>
        <property name="Node Group"></property>
    </accessPolicyProvider>
```

And

```
        <identifier>file-user-group-provider</identifier>
        <class>org.apache.nifi.authorization.FileUserGroupProvider</class>
        <property name="Users File">./conf/users.xml</property>
        <property name="Legacy Authorized Users File"></property>

        <property name="Initial User Identity 1">CN=nifi-admin,OU=NIFI</property>
    </userGroupProvider>
```

After making these changes, i started nifi and tried to connect using nipyapi code. I could see authentication sucess but authorization failed.

```
2019-08-11 05:08:04,014 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-16] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Checking secure context token: CN=nifi-admin, OU=NIFI
2019-08-11 05:08:04,014 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-16] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Checking secure context token: CN=nifi-admin, OU=NIFI
2019-08-11 05:08:04,014 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-16] o.a.n.w.s.NiFiAuthenticationFilter Checking secure context token: CN=nifi-admin, OU=NIFI
2019-08-11 05:08:04,014 DEBUG [NiFi Web Server-16] o.a.n.w.s.a.NiFiAnonymousUserFilter SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it already contained: 'CN=nifi-admin, OU=NIFI'
2019-08-11 05:08:04,016 INFO [NiFi Web Server-16] o.a.n.w.a.c.AccessDeniedExceptionMapper identity[CN=nifi-admin, OU=NIFI], groups[] does not have permission to access the requested resource. No applicable policies could be found. Returning Forbidden response.
```

In addition, here is user.xml and authorizations.xml

```
<tenants>
    <groups/>
    <users>
        <user identifier="94c8e1f5-aec4-3c99-8647-b61482c2ec0c" identity="CN=nifi-admin,OU=NIFI"/>
      </users>
</tenants>
```

```
<authorizations>
    <policies>
        <policy identifier="f99bccd1-a30e-3e4a-98a2-dbc708edc67f" resource="/flow" action="R">
            <user identifier="94c8e1f5-aec4-3c99-8647-b61482c2ec0c"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="bb8f03ca-de27-3f4a-9499-562a6c743fb0" resource="/data/process-groups/7b350728-016c-1000-8510-e66d31774eed" action="R">
            <user identifier="94c8e1f5-aec4-3c99-8647-b61482c2ec0c"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="395c506d-1368-3989-b2f2-6ea7218eb46e" resource="/data/process-groups/7b350728-016c-1000-8510-e66d31774eed" action="W">
            <user identifier="94c8e1f5-aec4-3c99-8647-b61482c2ec0c"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="ee1b66ee-7dac-3f09-8090-2b6803bd15c1" resource="/process-groups/7b350728-016c-1000-8510-e66d31774eed" action="R">
            <user identifier="94c8e1f5-aec4-3c99-8647-b61482c2ec0c"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="033157d8-93bd-3eea-8660-e3764d1017a2" resource="/process-groups/7b350728-016c-1000-8510-e66d31774eed" action="W">
            <user identifier="94c8e1f5-aec4-3c99-8647-b61482c2ec0c"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="b8775bd4-704a-34c6-987b-84f2daf7a515" resource="/restricted-components" action="W">
            <user identifier="94c8e1f5-aec4-3c99-8647-b61482c2ec0c"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="627410be-1717-35b4-a06f-e9362b89e0b7" resource="/tenants" action="R">
            <user identifier="94c8e1f5-aec4-3c99-8647-b61482c2ec0c"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="15e4e0bd-cb28-34fd-8587-f8d15162cba5" resource="/tenants" action="W">
            <user identifier="94c8e1f5-aec4-3c99-8647-b61482c2ec0c"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="ff96062a-fa99-36dc-9942-0f6442ae7212" resource="/policies" action="R">
            <user identifier="94c8e1f5-aec4-3c99-8647-b61482c2ec0c"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="ad99ea98-3af6-3561-ae27-5bf09e1d969d" resource="/policies" action="W">
            <user identifier="94c8e1f5-aec4-3c99-8647-b61482c2ec0c"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="2e1015cb-0fed-3005-8e0d-722311f21a03" resource="/controller" action="R">
            <user identifier="94c8e1f5-aec4-3c99-8647-b61482c2ec0c"/>
        </policy>
        <policy identifier="c6322e6c-4cc1-3bcc-91b3-2ed2111674cf" resource="/controller" action="W">
            <user identifier="94c8e1f5-aec4-3c99-8647-b61482c2ec0c"/>
        </policy>
    </policies>
</authorizations>
```

Comment: When you create the certificate, try to put a space `"CN=nifi-admin, OU=NIFI"`

Comment: No Change. It is still the same

Comment: As you can find in the log, nifi recognize your admin as "CN=nifi-admin, OU=NIFI" which include a space. Thus, I created the certificate with "CN=nifi-admin, OU=NIFI" and set the values in the config, too.

Comment: Yes use a space in the initial identity / initial admin identity values. After making changes in authorizes.xml, delete users.xml and authorizations.xml before restarting so that those files are regenerated.

Comment: I think i figured out the issue. I was trying to access Nifi using API calls and by default, the 'Initial Admin Identity' user is not provided. Refer ```For a brand new secure flow, providing the "Initial Admin Identity" gives that user access to get into the UI and to manage users, groups and policies. But if that user wants to start modifying the flow, they need to grant themselves policies for the root process group.```

Comment: That's true. I also got the permission by my self to give the policies.

Comment: You may find it convenient to use the nipyapi.security.bootstrap_security_policies method in future, as it sets obvious polices by default.